# How to create composite key in Objecty?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have the following `Entity` to be created in GAE datastore using Objectify.

```
@Entity
class TestEntity {

    Long deviceId;
    Long userId;
    boolean status

}
```

Here, I cannot make either the `deviceId` or `userId` as primary key (`@Id`), since a many-to-many relationship exists between them. So, I want to make the combination of `deviceId` and `userId` as the primary key, so as to avoid duplicate entries.

I do not have any clue as of how to do it. Can somebody please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want create key as a combination of `deviceId` and `userId` you can create additional field which holds such value.

```
@Entity
class TestEntity {
    @Id
    String key;
    Long deviceId;
    Long userId;
    boolean status

    public TestEntity(Long deviceId, Long userId) {
        key = deviceId.toString() +"|" +userId;
        //its better to separate them to avoid conflict
        //{123,1} vs {12,31}
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Best to add a separator so that {123,1} and {12,31} don't conflict.

Comment: @stickfigure Yes you're right, I've not thought about this. For sure it's recommended to use some kind of separator between these values to make the key unique.